# PowerShell: dealing with JSON using its native shorter command?

Tags: json, powershell, jq

I usually use JQ to handle JSON.

```
PS C:\> gc pw.txt
{
    "PowerShell": {
        "is a task": {
            "automation": [
                {
                    "and": "configuration",
                    "management": [
                        {
                            "program": "from",
                            "microsoft": {
                                "consisting of": "a command-line",
                                "shell": {
                                    "and": "the",
                                    "associated": {
                                        "scripting": {
                                            "language.": "initially a windows",
                                            "component": {
                                                "only": "known as",
                                                "windows": {
                                                    "powershell": "7.3.9-win-x64.msi",
                                                    "it was made": "open-source"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "the former": "is built on the .NET Framework",
                    "the latter on": ".NET (previously .NET Core)."
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

The following method works well in PowerShell to get the value `7.3.9-win-x64.msi` from the JSON above:

```
PS C:\> gc pw.txt | jq -r '.[] | .[] | .[] | .[].management | .[0].microsoft | .shell.associated.scripting.component.windows.powershell'
```

So, now how do I get the same value, without using JQ, but using the built-in utility in PowerShell itself (as much as possible with shorter commands) ?.

Comment: What is "the native method from PowerShell"?

Comment: I read posts about `ConvertFrom-Json`, also `ConvertTo-Json`, piped with `Select` or `Select-Object`. I've tried it, unfortunately it always fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$jsonObject=gc pw.txt | ConvertFrom-JSON
$jsonObject.powershell."is a task".automation[0].management[0].microsoft.shell.associated.scripting.component.windows.powershell
```